# How to create a Row Number cloumn in RadGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have a RadGridView with some rows, but I need a Row Number column. I make it with this code:

```
private void GridViewOrder_CellFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name == "RowNumber" && string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.CellElement.Text))
    {
        e.CellElement.Value = e.CellElement.RowIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

But my problem is, when I filter the grid, I want to have a new row number with the filtered grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
    void radGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name == "DecimalColumn" )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(radGridView1.ChildRows.IndexOf(e.Row));
            e.CellElement.Text = (e.CellElement.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="#" UniqueName="RowNumber">
                        <HeaderStyle Width="3%" Height="25px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true">
                        </HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle Height="35px" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# Container.DataSetIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you filter datagridview, then the datasource of the grid will change, The datasource will be DataView.
I think you should handle DataGridView.DataSourceChanged Event ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasourcechanged(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasourcechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), then loop through the new data source and set the value of "RowNumber" column.

Comment: Thanks,but i'm using radgridview telerik grid,and it does not have datasourceChaned event

Comment: you can add a column (RowNumber) in your data source, then you should update the value of this column in your DataView (the new data source) after filtering the grid.

Answer (score 0):

may this project help you, it show you how to customize the row template
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/WPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa